# How can I connect a HotRod client to an infinispan-cluster-cache server?

Tags: java, redhat, infinispan, nosql

I am trying to create a `HotRod` client to connect to an `infinispan-cluster-cache` but I am getting this error in the client:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1.jbossorg-3:java (default-cli) on project javaAPI: An exception occurred while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: End of stream reached! -> [Help 1]

And in the server, I get:

> WARN [TCP] (ConnectionMap.Acceptor [127.0.0.1:7800],null) JGRP000006: failed accepting connection from peer java.net.SocketException: ConnectionMap.Connection.readPeerAddress(): cookie read by 127.0.0.1:7800 does not match own cookie; terminating connection.

Has someone had a similar issue, or has any idea where I should look for the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the ports; HotRod server usually runs on port 11222, the port 7800 is used for JGroups = inter-node communication.

Comment: How can I set socket-binding port in library mode.?

Comment: Paste a link to your configuration (standalone.xml) and properties/programmatic configuration given to Hotrod clients.